Is this code "idiomatic" or generally good style haskell programming?
import System.Random
main :: IO()
main = do
    putStrLn "Enter range for guessing game"
    putStrLn "Enter lower range: "
    lRange <- getLine
    putStrLn "Enter higher range: "
    hRange <- getLine
    putStrLn "You try to guess it."
    play (randomInt (read lRange) (read hRange)) 0

play :: Integer -> Integer -> IO ()
play number guesses = 
    do
        guess <- getLine
        let guessInt = read guess :: Integer
        let newGuesses = guesses + 1
        putStrLn $ reactToGuess guessInt number
        if guessInt == number
            then putStrLn ("Correct!!! You found the number in " ++ show newGuesses ++ " guesses!")
            else play number newGuesses


reactToGuess :: Integer -> Integer -> String
reactToGuess x y
  | x < y = "You are too low."
  | x > y = "You are too high."
  | otherwise = ""

randomInt :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
randomInt l h = fst $ randomR (l,h) (mkStdGen 0)

I have bought the "Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!" book.
Only about 1/3 into the book. Trying to write something myself.
Is this how one would/should write this program in haskell?
Two questions focused really but I would like broad feedback on the whole program if possible.
1.
In reactToGuess could otherwise not lead to a empty line being printed?
| otherwise = ""


String contataion. Is ++ operator or <> operator best?
("Correct!!! You found the number in " ++ show newGuesses ++ " guesses!")




Well, one problem is that you're "random" int will be the exact same number every time, so it's just random in the xkcd sense. A simple fix would be to just use getStdRandom instead.

Note that while this isn't in itself a bad question to ask, this may be better suited to Code Review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/
as you're asking for feedback, not about solving a particular problem.

One simple improvement: replace reactToGuess and the if inside of play with case compare guessInt number of ...

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Before you post at [codereview.se], be sure to read A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users, as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code is for, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  Be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.

I'm somewhat surprised that Data.Ord doesn't define something like ordering :: a -> a -> a -> Ordering -> a, analogous to Data.Bool.bool.

For toys, I'd use the *IO variants of random number generation.
main = do
   ...
   number <- randomRIO (read lRange, read hRange)
   play number 0

Don't transition to the non-IO variants until you either need repeatability (i.e. seeding) or are trying to interoperate with an existing monad stack that doesn't include IO. Even then I strongly recommend something like MonadRandom to keep track of your RNG's internal state more easily, so you won't be escaping writing monadic code.
When in IO, you should pretty much always use readIO over read. It has better exceptional behavior, throwing the exception where the error happens rather than where it's noticed. (Try entering the letter x at the first prompt to see the difference.)
main = do
   ...
   lRangeString <- getLine
   lRange <- readIO lRangeString
   ...

The existing readLn packages this pattern up for you conveniently.
main = do
    ...
    lRange <- readLn
    ...

Rather than using <, >, and ==, consider using compare. This makes it easy for human and computer alike to see that all the cases are covered.
reactToGuess x y = case compare x y of
    LT -> "You are too low."
    GT -> "You are too high."
    EQ -> ""

I'd probably inline reactToGuess, since you're about to make other decisions than just what to print based on the result of the comparison.
play number guesses = do
   ...
   case compare guessInt number of
       LT -> putStrLn "You are too low." >> play number newGuesses
       GT -> putStrLn "You are too high." >> play number newGuesses
       EQ -> putStrLn ("Correct!!! You found the number in " ++ show newGuesses ++ " guesses!")

You could consider using printf for this last one, though I'm on the fence about this particular advice. It is nice that you don't have to manually call show and ++, but the printf machinery can be a bit complex for a beginner that really wants to understand the tools they're using. Also, printf occupies a sort of awkward spot in pretty-printer library space; usually by the time you want to graduate from raw string operations, you are ready to move all the way to a pretty-printer library with better power and flexibility than printf can offer.
import Text.Printf

...
        EQ -> printf "Correct!!! You found the number in %d guesses!\n" newGuesses

Some more minor stuff: it's traditional to use a prime to indicate a new variant of a variable, e.g. guesses' rather than newGuesses. I'd also include a space between IO and (), and a newline between imports and code.
With all these changes, you'd be left with this:
import System.Random
import Text.Printf

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "Enter range for guessing game"
    putStrLn "Enter lower range: "
    lRange <- readLn
    putStrLn "Enter higher range: "
    hRange <- readLn
    putStrLn "You try to guess it."
    number <- randomRIO (lRange, hRange)
    play number 0

play :: Integer -> Integer -> IO ()
play number guesses = do
    guess <- readLn
    let guesses' = guesses + 1
    case compare guess number of
        LT -> putStrLn "You are too low." >> play number guesses'
        GT -> putStrLn "You are too high." >> play number guesses'
        EQ -> printf "Correct!!! You found the number in %d guesses!\n" guesses'

